# Wifi not working on Ubuntu Dual Boot with windows 8.1 ( ASUS X550LD )

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

Hey guys i recently dual booted Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop ASUS X550LD. The dual boot works perfectly but wifi doesnt connect in Ubuntu.

It connects on Windows 8 perfectly. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
3:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6605]
 Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: 3:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6605]
 Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

@Pilot6

Comment: Do you have connection to internet by wire in Ubuntu?

Comment: I will try and i will take you about it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a wired internet connection just run in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: I d'ont have internet access !